# Use merge! or deep_merge! to update hash in activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, merge, activeadmin

I have a JSON column in my model that by default is an empty hash.

I want to check if specific keys are present and if not to merge the empty hash with a default hash with the keys.

In my model I am checking if a utility (water, gas, or electric is present) and if not then insert this default hash:

```
def default_config
    {:config => {"features" => {"utilities" => {"water" => true, "gas" => true, "electric" => true}}}}
end
```

this is how I'm checking for whether a utility key is present:

```
  def water 
    has_water? || parent.has_water?
  end
```

which in turn calls these methods (all in my model):

```
  def utility(util)
    self[:config].try(:fetch, "features", nil).try(:fetch, "utilities", nil).try(:fetch, "#{util}", nil)
  end

  def has_water?
    utility("water") == true
  end
```

This is in order to be able to configure the JSON column whether or not the keys already present, which I'm attempting here:

```
 def set_water(boolean) 
    new_val = cleaned_boolean(boolean)
    water ? nil : self[:config].deep_merge!(default_config)
    self[:config]["features"]["utilities"]["water"] = new_val
  end
```

When I test this I'm getting

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

error when trying to set a utility value indicating that my `default_config` is not being merged into the existing empty hash.

Comment: You could try using `pry-byebug` and putting a breakpoint with `binding.pry` to see what is actually being assigned to each var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reverse_merge!`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/reverse_merge) is the usual way to set defaults for a `Hash` in `rails`.

```
self[:config].reverse_merge!(default_config)
```

this is essentially equal to:

```
default_config.merge!(self[:config])
```

Leaving everything in `self[:config]` untouched and just merging in the missing key value pairs from `default_config`.

Also this ternary expression:

```
water ? nil : self[:config].deep_merge!(default_config)
```

is more idiomatically written as (using `Hash#reverse_merge!`)

```
self[:config].reverse_merge!(default_config) unless water
```

and since `water` returns a `boolean` value it is generally written as a question e.g. `water?` (like in `has_water?`) Not sure if the `water` method is used frequently but I would refactor as

```
def has_water?(include_parent=false)
  utility("water") == true || (include_parent && parent.has_water?)
end
```

Then call as:

```
self[:config].reverse_merge!(default_config) unless has_water?(true)
```